# Return ArrayList from void AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I `Googled` alot, but no chance for this.
For now, i a have an `Inner AsyncTask` class that i want to use the return values in the upper class.
And it successfully work, cause i have put a `Log.e()` and it shows my value, Here is my code :

```
   public class Consume extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private List<LatLng> latLngs = new ArrayList<>();
        private List<ContactModel> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        String result = "";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String URL = "http://x.x.x.x/MYWCF/Service1.svc/Json/getContact";
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> param = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            try {
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
                post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(param));
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(post);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                Log.e("UnsupportedEncoding", e1.toString());
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e2) {
                Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e2.toString());
                e2.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e3) {
                Log.e("IllegalStateException", e3.toString());
                e3.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e4) {
                Log.e("IOException", e4.toString());
                e4.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                String line = null;
                while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sBuilder.append(line + "\n");
                }
                inputStream.close();
                result = sBuilder.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("StringBuilding", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            List<ContactModel> contactModels;
            List<LatLng> myLatLngs = new ArrayList<>();
            try {

                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONArray jArray = object.getJSONArray("getContactResult");

                Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ContactModel>>() {
                }.getType();
                contactModels = new Gson().fromJson(String.valueOf(jArray), listType);
                setContacts(contactModels);

                setContacts(contactModels);
                for(ContactModel contactModel : contactModels) {
                    Double latitude = Double.valueOf(contactModel.getLatitude());
                    Double longitude = Double.valueOf(contactModel.getLongitude());
                    LatLng latLong = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                    myLatLngs.add(latLong);
                }
                setLatLngs(myLatLngs);
                Log.e("SizeOfArray", myLatLngs.size()+"");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    public void setContacts(List<ContactModel> contacts) {
        this.contacts = contacts;
    }

    public List<ContactModel> getContacts() {
        return contacts;
    }

    public void setLatLngs(List<LatLng> latLngs) {
        this.latLngs = latLngs;
    }
    public List<LatLng> getLatLngs() {
        return latLngs;
    }
```

And in my `Activity Class` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.osmdroid_map);


    Consume consume = new Consume();
    consume.execute();
```

When i run the app, cause of the line :

```
                Log.e("SizeOfArray", myLatLngs.size()+"");
```

it returns me the correct int number of array size in `logcat`, But i want to use that in my App,
I even do all stuff in `doInBackground` method, and even make a `static` variable,
No chance.
Can any one give a real sample by my code?
Thx

Comment: Call a function within `onPostExecute` and pass myLatLngs.size() to it then do what ever you planning to do.

Comment: I did it befor, no chance, i pass the whole array, cause i need the whole array.
I did it bu setContacts(ArrayListOfContactModel) and then in my onCreate called as : consume.getContacts();
No luck.

Comment: if i may ask what you planning to use `myLatLngs.size()` in ?

Comment: Its just a test, actually i need the myLatLngs in the main class.
I just do it to see if it returns actual size or not.

Comment: make a new void called AsyncReturn `public void AsyncReturn()` and pass the result to it within your AsyncTask's onPostExecute. It's so simple man :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx all, for all replies.
Thx, I really did not understand what the problem is and cause of that i asked this simple question ! And unfortunately none of you notice that.
After the code :

```
Consume consume = new Consume();
consume.execute():
```

Compiler goes to execute next code too,Cause consume.execute() start another thread but the main thread continues.
Cause of that i received the value i wanted with a delay and therefore i though the problem is how to get the value, 
But actually the problem was that i could not handle the thread asynchronization.
So i moved all them in `onPre` and `onPost` methods of AsyncTask class,And then it worked !

Answer (score 0):

First of all I will say that you should use static inner class instead of non-static inner class to avoid memory leaks as non-static inner class holds reference to the outer class. Another thing is that you can pass a `WeakReference` of outer parent class so that you can return the value from `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask like

```
public static class Consume extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    WeakReference<MainActivity> mActivity;

    public Consume(MainActivity activity){
        mActivity = new WeakReference<SampleActivity>(activity);
     }
}
```

In your AsyncTask's `onPostExecute` method it will be

```
mActivity.response(latLngs);
```

And in your other class it will be like

```
private static void response(List<LatLng> latLngs){
   // handle response here in your outer class
}
```

**Update**: [Here](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/01/inner-class-handler-memory-leak.html) is how you can pass WeakReference of Activity to Inner or Anonymous class and use it.

Comment: What you mean by activity.response(latLngs);
whats activity here?

Comment: @T_O its the WeakReference instance!

Answer (score 0):

As far as your AsyncTask class is an inner class. It can directly access objects of outer class.

Create an object of below at your outer class level.

```
List<LatLng> myLatLngs = new ArrayList<>();
```

And remove same from inner class so that single object instance will be their.

Another approach will be to use callback from your inner asyntask you need to have interface callback to outer class to start further process.

```
interface CallBack {
    public void processingDone();
}

Consume consume = new Consume(new CallBack() {
   @Override
   public void processingDone(List<LatLng> mLatLngs) {
     // Do your stuff here
   }
});
consume.execute();
```

And inside your Consume constructor store callback to pass data back to outer class.

```
class Consume {
  private Callback mCallback;
  public Consume(Callback callback) {
     mCallback = callback;
  }
}
```

And from below link you can do

```
if (mCallback != null) {
  mCallback.processingDone(myLatLngs);
}
Log.e("SizeOfArray", myLatLngs.size()+"");
```